# Convert array of objects containing bytes of user used languages in GitHub repo to a simpler array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a data which comes from GitHub Api `https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-languages`.
It is a Array of objects of every repository of specified user, the first problem is that the value shown for each language is the number of bytes of code written in that language.
So it looks like this:

```
data = [
  {
    repoName: "Docker_Kubernetes_Labs",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 64677,
      HTML: 17832,
      CSS: 8154,
      Dockerfile: 2859,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "Frontend-HTTP-MQTT-Project",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 59038,
      SCSS: 4732,
      CSS: 4281,
      HTML: 1925,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "frontend-prj",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 16730,
      SCSS: 5388,
      HTML: 1721,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "JavaProjects",
    languages: {
      Java: 42040,
    },
  },
];
```

What I would like to change, is to sum all of the languages used, and display percentages so for all repositorys it would look like this:

```
{
    JavaScript: 0.55,
    SCSS: 0.1,
    CSS: 0.1,
    HTML: 0.1,
    Java: 0.1,
    Dockerfile: 0.05
}
```

I just want it to be summing up to 100% or 1 or 100, because I want to create a Pie-chart with these data, But also I want to be able to have a list of all repositories, so the final data would look like this:

```
expected_output = [
  {
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 0.55,
      SCSS: 0.1,
      CSS: 0.1,
      HTML: 0.1,
      Java: 0.1,
      Dockerfile: 0.05,
    },
    repositories: [
      "Docker_Kubernetes_Labs",
      "Frontend-HTTP-MQTT-Project",
      "frontend-prj",
      "JavaProjects",
    ],
  },
];
```

And for me it's to much, firstly I do not know how to conver those bytes into percentages so they sum up to 100, and secondly I do not know how to display this data in a simpler  way.

Comment: Calculate the total of all the bytes. Then divide each one by the total to calculate its percentage. This is high school math.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, you need to find someone to write your application. We're not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to aggregate all languages (sum total bytes per language), then you can calculate percentages using basic math.

```js
const data = [{
    repoName: "Docker_Kubernetes_Labs",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 64677,
      HTML: 17832,
      CSS: 8154,
      Dockerfile: 2859,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "Frontend-HTTP-MQTT-Project",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 59038,
      SCSS: 4732,
      CSS: 4281,
      HTML: 1925,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "frontend-prj",
    languages: {
      JavaScript: 16730,
      SCSS: 5388,
      HTML: 1721,
    },
  },
  {
    repoName: "JavaProjects",
    languages: {
      Java: 42040,
    },
  },
];


// AGGREGATE LANGUAGES
const res = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  a.repositories.push(b.repoName)
  for (const lang of Object.keys(b.languages)) {
    if (a.languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) {
      a.languages[lang] += b.languages[lang]
    } else {
      a.languages[lang] = b.languages[lang]
    }
  }
  return a
}, { languages: {}, repositories: [] })


// GET TOTAL BYTES
const totBytes = Object.values(res.languages).reduce((a, b) => a + b)


// CALCULATE PERCENTAGES
for (const lang of Object.keys(res.languages)) {
  res.languages[lang] = res.languages[lang] / totBytes
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
JavaScript: 64677,
HTML: 17832,
CSS: 8154,
Dockerfile: 2859,
```

```
sum = 64677 + 17832 + 8154 + 2859 = 93522

JavaScript: 64677 / sum = 0.69,
HTML: 17832 / sum = 0.19,
CSS: 8154 / sum = 0.09,
Dockerfile: 2859 / sum = 0.03,
```

To do it in code I would use `reduce`

```js
const languages = {
  JavaScript: 64677,
  HTML: 17832,
  CSS: 8154,
  Dockerfile: 2859,
}

const sum = Object.values(languages).reduce((sum, r) => sum + r)
const percentages = Object.entries(languages).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  obj[key] = value / sum
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(percentages)
```